# Cannot use GMail Api from Service Account because of invalid grant

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm trying to read GMail messages using their [API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/) from a .NET service application. Hence, i'm using a "[Service Account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount)" (those which not requires the user to interactively confirm access and are designed to be used in a service-to-service way).

So, I have the following code...

```
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;

using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1;
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data;

namespace Test
{
  public class MyClient
  {
    public List<Message> GetMyMessages()
    {
        var serviceAccountId = "MyServiceAccountId.apps.googleusercontent.com";
        var serviceEMailAddress = "MyServiceEMailAddress@developer.gserviceaccount.com";    // Not required?
        var certificatePwd = "thesecret";
        var userEMailAccount = "user@gmail.com";

        var certFile = File.ReadAllBytes("MyCert.p12");

        var cert = new X509Certificate2(certFile, certificatePwd, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
        var scopes = new string[] { GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom };  // Also tried with: GmailService.Scope.GmailCompose and GmailService.Scope.GmailModify

        var currentCredential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
            new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountId)
        {
            User = userEMailAccount,
            Scopes = scopes
        }.FromCertificate(cert));

        var service = new GmailService(new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer
        {
            ApplicationName = "MyApp",
            HttpClientInitializer = currentCredential
        });

        var Messages = new List<Message>();
        var request = service.Users.Messages.List(userEMailAccount);
        request.MaxResults = 3;
        // request.Q = "";

        do
        {
            try
            {
                var response = request.Execute();
                Messages.AddRange(response.Messages);
                request.PageToken = response.NextPageToken;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // throws exception with message: Error:"invalid_grant", Description:"", Uri:""
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
            }
        } while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.PageToken));

        return Messages;
     }
   }
}
```

That Works fine until calling the request.Execute() method, which fails with the next exception: Error:"invalid_grant", Description:"", Uri:""

So, what I'm missing? what's wrong with it?

Comment: I think you should read up on Oath.  A service account does not have a gmail account.   User is just a text string used to create the authentication, you could put blah in there and it would do the same.   That being said you cant use Gmail with a service account.  Try Oauth2.

Comment: Should get you started: http://www.daimto.com/how-to-access-gmail-with-c-net/  https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/tree/master/Google-Gmail

Comment: Wow, if anyone has a solution to this problem, this is exactly where I am stuck.

Comment: Same problem still exists. Anyone got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

[Official documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#service_account) says that:

> Your client application signs the request for an access token using a
>   private key downloaded from the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/). After
>   creating a new client ID, you should choose a “Service Account”
>   application type and then you can download the private key. Take a
>   look at our [service account sample using Google Plus API](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/?repo=samples#hg%2FPlus.ServiceAccount).

So the error you got, as I see, can be caused by wrong key in your application. May be you didn't update it or something.

Don't forget to change the Build action to `Content` and the Copy to Output Directory to `Copy if newer` for the key you've downloaded from Google API site.

Comment: Hi [VMAtm], I analyzed the example and detected that (for the ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer constructor) it passes the service account email instead of the service account id. So, I tried with that, but it throws other exception:  Error:"unauthorized_client", Description:"Unauthorized client or scope in request.", Uri:""